# The file "prueba.jpeg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error

Tags: symfony3, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

Tengo configurado el subir imagenes correctamente en el admin y segui esta documentacion: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/vichuploaderbundle.html

Ahora en otra parte del sistema que no utiliza EasyAdminBundle necesito subir imagenes, en el controlador tengo esto:

```
public function crearequiposAction(Request $request) {
    $equipo = new Equipos();
    $form = $this->createForm(EquiposType::class, $equipo);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $fecha=new \DateTime('now');

            $ruta = $equipo->getImageFile();
            $nombrep = $equipo->getLogo();
            $nombre = $nombrep.'.'.$ruta->guessExtension();

            $fileDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads/images/equipos';

            $ruta->move(
                $fileDir,
                $nombre
            );


            $equipo->setLogo($nombre);
            $equipo->setUpdatedAt($fecha);


            $em->persist($equipo);
            $flush = $em->flush();

                if ($flush == null) {
                    $status = "Documento registrado correctamente";

                    $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("status", $status);
                    return $this->redirectToRoute("listado-torneos");

                } else {
                    $status = "No se registro equipo";
                }

        } else {
            $status = "No se registro equipo";
        }

        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("status", $status);
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Equipos:informacionequipos.html.twig', array(
                "form" => $form->createView()
    ));
```

}

La imagen sube correctamente pero me muestra este error:

> The file "prueba.jpeg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se como solucionar este problema, alguna idea?

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la solución, el problema estaba en 2 partes:

Primero es necesario cambiar el código del formulario a esto:

```
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

$builder
          ->add('nombre')
          ->add('grupo')
          ->add('numero')
          ->add('imageFile', VichFileType::class)
          ->add('torneos')
          ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                     "attr" => array(
                     "class" => "save"
                )));
```

El segundo cambio es en el controlador, cuando se usa el bundle no es necesario utilizar la línea del `move`, esto solo se utiliza cuando se sube imágenes de forma nativa.

Este es el código del controlador:

```
public function crearequiposAction(Request $request) {
        $equipo = new Equipos();
        $form = $this->createForm(EquiposType::class, $equipo);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($equipo);
                $flush = $em->flush();
                    if ($flush == null) {
                        $status = "Equipo registrado correctamente";
                        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("status", $status);
                        return $this->redirectToRoute("listado-torneos");
                    } else {
                        $status = "No se registro equipo";
                    }
            } else {
                $status = "No se registro equipo";
            }
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("status", $status);
        }
        return $this->render('AppBundle:Equipos:informacionequipos.html.twig', array(
                    "form" => $form->createView()
        ));
  }
```

Saludos